# ASP.NET MVC 4: How to update model from view on submit form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I create some form and I need to assign field `CreationDate` on submit form:

```
@model Namespaces.Chapter

@using (Html.BeginForm ()) {
    <p>Title: @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Title)</p>
    ...
    @{ Model.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;} <- somehow like that, but this code does not works
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: You should set the creation date in your controller. If you set is client side, your trusting that your client's clock is accurate.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this in the controller action before passing it to data access like:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeClass obj)
{
   obj.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;

   // your business logic goes here
   ................
   ................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also put the following tag in your form:

```
<input type='datetime' asp-for='CreationDate' />
```